# Should Charger, Charging, and battery charger tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have the [charger](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charger), [charging](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charging), and [battery-charging](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battery-charging) tags, should they be merged?

There are a few questions marked as charging that relate to capacitor and inductor charging, but all of the others refer to battery chargers.

Comment: It could be a problem for Dodge hackers!

Comment: Seriously, could "charging" be associated to anything else than batteries? I think they could be merged...

Comment: @clabacchio charging can be associated with "charging a capacitor"

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but I'm not sure anyone will ever ask how to charge a capacitor...I don't know...

Comment: @clabacchio, there can be some complexity to charging a cap, I think that charging is a useless tag myself, always needing to have capacitor or battery to be useful.

Comment: @clabacchio The problem is questions like http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/18593/capacitors-fluid-models-and-pumps and http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/14462/what-do-you-call-it-when-you-add-energy-to-an-inductor We probably need to manual changing of tags instead of bulk changing all of them.

Comment: @Kellenjb If you (not necessarily you specifically, but at least someone from the community) clean up the questions that need manual retagging, the rest can be dealt with in a bulk way (by merging or deleting the tag).

Comment: How about dV/dt for the capacitor charging ...  ;)

Answer (score 3):

The charger and battery-charging tags should be merged anyway, there is no way they can refer to something different.

There of course are questions that are related to capacitor charging, but they can have the tag charge instead. In common sense, the word charging refers to battery charging, and the few questions about capacitor charging can be re-tagged manually. In my opinion, it's just useless to have the battery-charging and charging tag, while almost everyone adds both to their posts, or only battery-charging since it's more specific.

So I'd say we merge battery-charging and charger anyway, and, but that's more debatable, merge them to charging as well.